# Extract data from an unreachable JsonObject()

Tags: json, beautifulsoup, python-requests, algolia

I'm trying to reach a JsObject to scrape it.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url ='https://fjrgcwbcbo-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/*/queries?x-algolia-agent=Algolia%20for%20vanilla%20JavaScript%20(lite)%203.27.0%3Binstantsearch.js%202.8.0%3BJS%20Helper%202.26.0&x-algolia-application-id=FJRGCWBCBO&x-algolia-api-key=a214a1e7afd822b517723830f05e9449'
jsonObj = requests.get(url).json()

print(JsonObj)
```

There are four JsonObject from this URL, but each one seems to be blocked by an API.
[Website URL](https://www.capifrance.fr/conseillers?locationText=france&adresse=france)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's a permissions error, meaning you're doing something wrong to access it. Not much someone on the outside could do, but I would first remove the space from the query. `{"message":"Index not allowed with this API key","status":403}` is what I get when I fix the formatting errors in the query. Otherwise, I get `{"message":"indexName is not valid","status":400}` which means the URL and parameters isn't correct. Looks like your API key isn't valid.

Comment: Give me a minute, I figured it out and will post the solution momentarily as I type it up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find another solution to scrape all of the email adresses in one shot.

```
import requests
import json
from algoliasearch import algoliasearch

url ='https://fjrgcwbcbo- 
dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/*/queries'

client = algoliasearch.Client("FJRGCWBCBO", "a214a1e7afd822b517723830f05e9449")
index = client.init_index('CAPI-agents-stage')

for hit in index.browse_all({"query": ""}):
    print(hit['email_address'])
```

If it could help anyone, thanks a lot Chitown88

Answer (score 3):

It was tricky the way you need to feed in the query parameters and payload and figuring out how it receives it. But this does the trick:

```
import requests
import json

url ='https://fjrgcwbcbo-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/*/queries'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.119 Safari/537.36'}

params = {
'x-algolia-agent': 'Algolia for vanilla JavaScript (lite) 3.27.0;instantsearch.js 2.8.0;JS Helper 2.26.0',
'x-algolia-application-id': 'FJRGCWBCBO',
'x-algolia-api-key': 'a214a1e7afd822b517723830f05e9449'}

data = {"requests":[{"indexName":"CAPI-agents-stage","params":"query=&hitsPerPage=20&maxValuesPerFacet=10&page=0&filters=source.name%3Atremplin%20AND%20NOT%20source.id%3A400%20AND%20NOT%20source.id%3A2662%20AND%20NOT%20source.id%3A3292%20AND%20NOT%20source.id%3A720%20AND%20NOT%20source.id%3A1%20AND%20NOT%20source.id%3A5167%20AND%20NOT%20source.id%3A177%20AND%20NOT%20source.id%3A7907%20AND%20NOT%20source.id%3A4999%20AND%20NOT%20source.id%3A979%20AND%20NOT%20source.id%3A5538%20AND%20NOT%20source.id%3A8062%20AND%20NOT%20source.id%3A7908%20AND%20NOT%20source.id%3A38%20AND%20NOT%20source.id%3A7957%20AND%20NOT%20source.id%3A8084%20AND%20NOT%20source.id%3A8078%20AND%20NOT%20source.id%3A8158%20AND%20NOT%20source.id%3A9298%20AND%20NOT%20source.id%3A9299%20AND%20NOT%20source.id%3A9368%20AND%20NOT%20source.id%3A540%20AND%20NOT%20source.id%3A7905%20AND%20NOT%20source.id%3A10173&facets=%5B%22identity.last_name%22%2C%22geolocation.city%22%2C%22geolocation.postal_code%22%2C%22geolocation.region%22%2C%22geolocation.department%22%2C%22geolocation.country%22%2C%22specialities%22%5D&tagFilters="}]}
jsondata = json.dumps(data)

jsonObj = requests.post(url, data=jsondata, params=params).json()

print(jsonObj['results'][0])

for each in jsonObj['results'][0]['hits']:
    print (each['email_address'])
```

**Additional:**

I tweaked the way that you can alter the query/data parameters.

```
import requests
import urllib

url ='https://fjrgcwbcbo-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/*/queries'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.119 Safari/537.36'}

params = {
'x-algolia-agent': 'Algolia for vanilla JavaScript (lite) 3.27.0;instantsearch.js 2.8.0;JS Helper 2.26.0',
'x-algolia-application-id': 'FJRGCWBCBO',
'x-algolia-api-key': 'a214a1e7afd822b517723830f05e9449'}


#Utilize a simplier way to input query parameters
query = {
"indexName":"CAPI-agents-stage", 
"hitsPerPage": "20",
"maxValuesPerFacet": "10",
"page": "0",
"filters": "source.name:tremplin AND NOT source.id:400 AND NOT source.id:2662 AND NOT source.id:3292 AND NOT source.id:720 AND NOT source.id:1 AND NOT source.id:5167 AND NOT source.id:177 AND NOT source.id:7907 AND NOT source.id:4999 AND NOT source.id:979 AND NOT source.id:5538 AND NOT source.id:8062 AND NOT source.id:7908 AND NOT source.id:38 AND NOT source.id:7957 AND NOT source.id:8084 AND NOT source.id:8078 AND NOT source.id:8158 AND NOT source.id:9298 AND NOT source.id:9299 AND NOT source.id:9368 AND NOT source.id:540 AND NOT source.id:7905 AND NOT source.id:10173",
"facets": str(["identity.last_name","geolocation.city","geolocation.postal_code","geolocation.region","geolocation.department","geolocation.country","specialities"]),
"tagFilters": ""}

#Create the string for the data parameter using the urllib parse quote
data = '''{"requests": [{"indexName": "%s", "params": "query=&hitsPerPage=%s&maxValuesPerFacet=%s&page=%s&filters=%s&facets=%s&tagFilters=%s"}]}''' %(query['indexName'],query['hitsPerPage'],query['maxValuesPerFacet'],query['page'],urllib.parse.quote(query['filters']),urllib.parse.quote(query['facets']),query['tagFilters'])

jsonObj = requests.post(url, data=data, params=params).json()


print(jsonObj['results'][0])

for each in jsonObj['results'][0]['hits']:
    print (each['email_address'])
```

Comment: Wow, Thanks a lot !!!
Effectively, it seems to be very tricky  !
I'm looking Algolia docs to understand the way you did it.
Thanks.

Comment: the tricky part is the `data = {"requests":[{"indexName":"CAPI-agents-stage","params":"query=...` Normally, you'd just feed in a dictionary the way you see `headers` and `params` above. But the query string for that part (`data`), not only is a nested dictionary, but then also needs to be in the form a string. I'm still looking/working on it though to see if there's atleast a more compact way to do it. And ya, their documentation didn't help me too much.

Comment: I added a little something extra, to possible make it a little easier to input those data parameters. I don't exactly how it alters the results as I haven't played with it, but I can leave that up to you.

Comment: Yes, there is also a "paginationLimitedTo index parameter" limitation, I can scrapp the first thousand of email, but can't access the page 50.
I'm looking the doc for fix it.