# How to fix Algolia API call: {"message":"indexName is not valid","status":400}

Tags: python, ajax, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to get a list of the company names at this [URL](https://www.ycombinator.com/companies?isHiring=true&status=Active). Tried Selenium, but looks like I need to mirror the API call instead. Believe data is in this [request URL](https://45bwzj1sgc-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/*/queries?x-algolia-agent=Algolia%20for%20JavaScript%20(3.35.1)%3B%20Browser%3B%20JS%20Helper%20(3.4.4)&x-algolia-application-id=45BWZJ1SGC&x-algolia-api-key=Zjk5ZmFjMzg2NmQxNTA0NGM5OGNiNWY4MzQ0NDUyNTg0MDZjMzdmMWY1NTU2YzZkZGVmYjg1ZGZjMGJlYjhkN3Jlc3RyaWN0SW5kaWNlcz1ZQ0NvbXBhbnlfcHJvZHVjdGlvbiZ0YWdGaWx0ZXJzPSU1QiUyMnljZGNfcHVibGljJTIyJTVEJmFuYWx5dGljc1RhZ3M9JTVCJTIyeWNkYyUyMiU1RA%3D%3D) based on looking at the Network pings, but the URL links to a status 400 page.

Looks like I need a solution [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55061156/extract-data-from-an-unreachable-jsonobject) but I'm not sure how to tweak the query params to make it work

Appreciate any help, thank you!